# Recurrence T(n)=T(n/3+5) + T(2n/3+7) + O(1)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

How can I find the upper bound of the recurrence:

```
T(n) = T(n/3 + 5) + T(2n/3 + 7) + O(1)
```

without ignoring the "+5" and "+7"?

Comment: Well, you have a problem here when n <= 20.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Akra--Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), the solution is O(n), since 5 and 7 both are O(n/log^2 n).